# How to optimize query when there are hundreds of thousands of records in the table

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

Employee table contains one hundred thousand records.

```
SELECT name, job, sal, comm 
FROM employee
WHERE designation = (@userdefineddesignation).
```

How do I optimize this query?

Comment: what is *lakhs* and do you already have an index on designation?

Comment: I was asked this question in an interview, can you tell me the possible optimization techniques for this query.

Comment: Look into indexing. This is very basic. Maybe you should read a tutorial on databases in general.

Answer (score 2):

Check the indexes. There should be an index on `designation` column with include columns that are in select clause: `name`, `job`, `sal`, `comm`, in this specific case.

Check the execution plan before and after adding the index to see what difference it makes. Also, check the number of reads before and after.

Answer (score 0):

Look into indexes which exist on the employee table. Then run a execution plan based on query in mangt studio. Press ctrl L as short cut. Its also worth enabling statistics io on and viewing the logical and physical reads.